# Can I drive this chip with a signal to drive the output drives?

Tags: motor, dc-motor

[This](http://www.chip-hope.com/UploadFiles/pdf/LP2P13%20%E9%81%A5%E6%8E%A7%E7%8E%A9%E5%85%B7%E8%BD%A6%E6%8E%A7%E5%88%B6+%E9%A9%B1%E5%8A%A8%E8%8A%AF%E7%89%87%20V1.2.pdf) is the datasheet of the chip and I don't speak Chinese. I've tried google translate but with little success.

The chip is used in [this car](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000HH6KFA). I am trying to use a raspberry pi to drive it over wifi and I've got the raspberry pi working just fine. If I use a separate motor driver I can drive the motors just fine, but I was wondering if it's possible to use the chip already present to drive the motors. In other words use that as the motor driver. One way would be to "hack" the antenna signal but that's not what I'm after.

[This](http://www.adafruit.com/products/711?gclid=Cj0KEQjw2KyxBRCi2rK11NCDw6UBEiQAO-tljVg-8J4mtbKxu65CuLAYEK455qKW4W1mnkAGfFvoM_gaAoFG8P8HAQ) is the motor that I'm trying to drive if that's at all relevant.

Comment: I did a quick google translate of the LP2P13 chinese datasheet. Not the greatest format for EE.SE. Base on what I have presented you should be able to drive the motor. Feel free to updated the response as needed to make the response better

Comment: Honestly, it looks like nothing more than an H bridge driver. Just pick a part with an English datasheet. There's no reason to decipher foreign datasheets on a commodity part.

Comment: @MattYoung there is no English datasheet

Comment: He means to simply buy an H bridge driver with an English Datasheet which is what I've done

Answer (score 1):

LP2P13 from Mao Wuxi City Core Microelectronics Co is a basic H-bridge driver similar to a L298N. So this is capable of driving a motor. Also just like the Raspberry PI, their is most likely micro-controller that controls the LP2P13. So you have to figure how to get your Raspberry pi to communicate with the Micro-Controller.

I did a quick google translate of the datasheet. The format that is presented below is not too great. I have tried to map some of Chinese content to the translations. It appears there is sufficient information to help drive the motor.

Please feel free to edit the content make the content more readable

Chinese to English Translation using google translate for LP2P13 controller chips from chip-hope.

### LP2P13 - Chinese to English Translation

---

### LP2P13

Remote control toy car + driver chip
Product Specification
V1.2
Mao Wuxi City Core Microelectronics Co., Ltd.
www.chip-hope.com

---

Page 2
Eye Record
A chip overview .............................................. - 3 -
Second, the main features of .............................................. .................................................. ...........- 3 -
Third, Pin Description ............................................. .................................................. ............- 3 -
Fourth, the functional block diagram of .............................................. .................................................. ...........- 4 -
V. Functional Description .............................................. .................................................. ...........- 4 -
Sixth, application examples .............................................. .................................................. ...........- 6 -
Seven, the electrical characteristics .............................................. .................................................. ...........- 7--
Eight, packaging data .............................................. .................................................. ...........- 8 -
Nine, silk screen instructions .............................................. .................................................. ...........- 8 -
Mao Wuxi City Core Microelectronics Co., Ltd.
www.chip-hope.com

---

Page 3
LP2P13
Remote control toy car + driver chip
Mao Wuxi City Core Microelectronics Co., Ltd.
--3--
A chip overview.
LP2P13 toy designed for remote control cars and other brush DC motor control + driver chip. The conventional receiver chip +
Chip power-driven alternative to receive + drive single chip, reducing the peripheral device costs and improve reliability.
LP2P13 applies to section 2-3 batteries, most of the 4-cell applications. The chip has a large current drive capability,
Built-in clamp diode can release the reverse inrush current inductive load for motor drive safe and reliable. Overtemperature protection functions into
Further enhance the reliability of the system.

Second, the main features.

- And TX-2S with remote control cars to achieve a streamlined solution;
- Wide operating voltage range (VDD = 2V7V, recommended application in
  23 cell applications);
- Built-in 2-way full-bridge driver (power motor, steering motor), the
  drive capacity of up to 1.5A;
- Complete maneuverability (forward, backward, turn left, turn right,
  speed);
- With over-temperature protection;
- Low on-resistance of the power transistor (NMOS and PMOS active
  region resistors and is typically 0.4Ω);
- Using SOP16 package.

[image: Page 3]

Third, the pin description.

Table 1.
Remote + motor driven pin definitions
1 VO2 For signal amplification of the output of the inverter 2
2 SI Coded signal input terminal
3 OSCI Resistance oscillator input terminal
4 AGND The control section power supply ground
5 VM2 motor input power 2
6 Turn right OUT2A motor 2 output terminal B
7 Turn left OUT2B motor 2 output terminal A
8 GND2 motor to 2
9 GND1 Motor forward and back to 1
10 Back OUT1B Forward and back end of the motor 1 output B
11 Forward OUT1A A forward-backward motor 1 output terminal
12 VM1 Motor input power forward back 1
13 VDD The control section power supply positive terminal
14 VI1 1 input for signal amplification inverter
15 VO1 1 output for signal amplification inverter
16 VI2 2 inputs for signal amplification inverter

[image: Table 1 in Chinese]

Mao Wuxi City Core Microelectronics Co., Ltd.
www.chip-hope.com

---

Page 4
LP2P13
Remote control toy car + driver chip Mao Wuxi City Core Microelectronics Co., Ltd.
--4--
Fourth, the functional block diagram.

[image: Functional Black Diagram]

Fifth, the functional description.
1, over-temperature protection.
Enter when the junction temperature greater than 150 ° C standby, does not accept instruction, until the temperature decreased to 130 ° C, to restore normal operation
For instruction arrive after the action.
2, decoding frequency.
Chi Yu classic RC oscillator, in good temperature compensation based on the use Trimming resistor way to achieve
Indicators.
Timing Description (refer TX-2B and RX-2B):
Figure 2. The coding sequence (bit encoding format).

[image: Figure 2]

Figure 3. The coding sequence (word encoding format).

Mao Wuxi City Core Microelectronics Co., Ltd.
www.chip-hope.com
Mao Wuxi City Core Microelectronics Co., Ltd.
www.chip-hope.com

---

Page 5
LP2P13
Remote control toy car + driver chip Mao Wuxi City Core Microelectronics Co., Ltd.
--5--

[image: Figure 3]

Figure 4. decoding timing.

[image: Figure 4]

Mao Wuxi City Core Microelectronics Co., Ltd. www.chip-hope.com

---

Page 6
LP2P13
Remote control toy car + driver chip
Mao Wuxi City Core Microelectronics Co., Ltd.
--6--
Sixth, application examples.
1, a typical application (LP2P13, RF remote control + motor drive, electric cars, or remote control toys).
Component selection and layout recommendations:
1. Recommended programs in: C18 220uF electrolytic capacitor is, C3 to filter out high frequency noise of 104 capacitors, these two capacitors
As close to the RF section and 13 pins to the wiring. C15 220uF electrolytic capacitor as much as possible at the same time close to 5 feet and
12 feet. R18 is the resistance of the resistor 100Ω, this resistor do not exceed 100Ω.
2, cost savings programs: simultaneously remove C15 capacitor and resistor R18, but remote control distance may be affected. Prohibit the
The case is now only remove the capacitor C15 appears.
2, typical applications (LP2P13, infrared remote control + drive, electric cars, or remote control toys).
Mao Wuxi City Core Microelectronics Co., Ltd.
www.chip-hope.com

---

Page 7
LP2P13
Remote control toy car + driver chip
Mao Wuxi City Core Microelectronics Co., Ltd.
- 7 -
3, the reference application (TX-2S with the application, RF remote control transmitter, electric cars, or remote control toys).
Seven, the electrical characteristics.
Table 2. Absolute Maximum Ratings (TA = 25 ° C)

Parameters
Symbol
Value
Unit
The maximum control supply voltage
VDD (MAX)
7
V
Input and output voltage
VIN / VOUT
GND-0.3VDD + 0.3
V
The maximum output voltage applied
VOUT (MAX)
VDD
V
Maximum output current per channel (peak)
IOUT (MAX)
3.5
A
ESD capability (human body model)
3000
V

Table 3. 
The electrical parameters table (test condition VDD = 4.0V, TA = 25 ° C)
Parameters
Symbol
Least
Typical
Maximum
Unit
voltage VDD 2.0 - 7.0 V
Quiescent Current I Q - 1.4 - mA
OUT1 power transistor NMOS + PMOS conduction Resistance (ACTIVE) R ON1 - 0.4 Ohm
OUT2 power transistor NMOS + PMOS conduction Resistance (ACTIVE) R ON2 0.4 Ohm

[image: Table 3-1]

Mao Wuxi City Core Microelectronics Co., Ltd.
www.chip-hope.com

---

Page 8
LP2P13
Remote control toy car + driver chip
Mao Wuxi City Core Microelectronics Co., Ltd.
- 8 -

Over Temperature Protection Temperature TP - 150 - ℃
Over-temperature protection hysteresis temperature -
20 -
℃
Decoding frequency (REXT = 250k)
FOSC
118
128
138
kHz
Oscillator temperature coefficient
COSC
300
ppm
Logic high
VINH
2.0 - -
V
Logic low
VINL - -
0.8
V

[image: Table 3-2]

Eight, packaging data.

Nine, silk screen instructions.

among them
: Refers to the "Wuxi City Core Microelectronics Co., Ltd. Mao" Logo;
LP2P13: refers to the chip type;
XXXXXXXX: refers Wafer ID.
LP2P13
XXXXXXXX
Mao Wuxi City Core Microelectronics Co., Ltd.
www.chip-hope.com

---

**References:**

- [Motor Driver board: limited current](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/549/motor-driver-board-limited-current/555#555)
- [Full-Bridge Motor Driver Dual - L298N](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/General/L298N.pdf)